# tiling rectangle using triominos

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, rectangles, tiling

1. Is it possible to tile a 9x9 square using triominos?
2. Is it possible to tile a 9x9 square using triominos so all 8 horizontal and 8 vertical lines between tiles are intersecting at least one triomino?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any guess?

Comment: The only useful thing I found so far was Chu–Johnsonbaugh Theorem:
An  m×n rectangle can always be tiled by trominoes if  3|mn,  2≤m≤n, except for  3×(2k+1)rectangles where  k≥1. But I dont know how to prove it. Also, I know that every 3i x 2j or 2i x 3j rectangle can be tiled.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about proof (which, BTW, can be found by the [very first Google link](http://math.depaul.edu/mash/TileRec3b.pdf), and is quite mechanical and unexciting). Cut some [trominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino) (not [triominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triominoes), mind you) from cardboard paper and play with them for a while. Have fun. I mean, have fun the next time, because this time I'm going to claim the fun for myself.

[image: 9x9 in trominoes]